# Продолжение пути к объекту

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть например объект:

```
var obj = [{
    da: 'datext', 
    aa: 'aatext', 
    dt: 'dttext',
    local: {
        dan: 'dantext', 
        aan: 'aantext'
        }
    }, 
    {
    da: 'datext', 
    aa: 'aatext', 
    dt: 'dttext',
    local: {
        dan: 'dantext', 
        aan: 'aantext'
        }
    }];
```

нужно достать  obj[0].local.dan //dantext  собирая из кусков например у меня не получается:

```
var opath='["local"]["dan"]';
alert(obj[0]+opath); //[object object]["local"]["dan"]
```

Подскажите, как получить значения таким образом?

Comment: Либо так, либо думать в каком месте Вы сделали такую некорректную архитектуру, что Вам вообще потребовалось нечто подобное:  

    eval( "obj[0]"+'["local"]["dan"]' )

Comment: Еще можно вот так извратиться (функция неполная - она возвращает только первый элемент. Нужно делать рекурсию:  

    Object.prototype.path = function( pathText ) {
        var re = /\["([^"]+)"\]/;
        return this[ re.exec( pathText )[1] ];
    };
    obj[0].path( '["local"]' );

Comment: так да, работает, только вот надо именно    obj[0]+'["local"]["dan"]'

Comment: @ReinRaus спасибо, за идею, подтачил к eval)

Comment: А зачем `eval`? Он практически никогда не нужен. Чем плохо `obj[0]["local"]["dan"]`?